# How to configure SSH for remote development in vs-code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

I have access to a private VM in GCP that only have an internal IP, than after some research I learned that the only way to SSH into it for remote development in VS Code is via IAP tunnel.

So I generated the ssh keys by running the following gcloud command in  CLI.

```
gcloud compute ssh vm-instance-name -zone us-central1-a --tunnel-through-iap --dry-run
```

After this, I got the following response from the above command.

```
"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud-SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\sdk\putty.exe" -t -i C:\Users\username\.ssh\google_compute_engine.ppk -proxycmd ""C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Cloud-SDK\\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\\..\\platform\\bundledpython\\python.exe" "-S" "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Cloud-SDK\\google-cloud-sdk\\lib\\gcloud.py" compute start-iap-tunnel ssh-remote-vm %port --listen-on-stdin --project=project-name --zone=us-central1-a --verbosity=warning" rajamannar_k@compute.1363457738033948822
```

How should I configure /.ssh/configure to connect to the VM for remote development, or what command should be passed into the "Remote-SSH: add-new-host" option?

Below is the /.ssh/configure I have setup.

```
Host compute.1363457738033948822
    HostName compute.1363457738033948822
    IdentityFile C:\Users\rajamannar_k\.ssh\google_compute_engine
    CheckHostIP no
    UserKnownHostsFile C:\Users\rajamannar_k\.ssh\google_compute_known_hosts
    HostKeyAlias compute.1363457738033948822
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    ProxyCommand "C:\\Users\\rajamannar_k\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Cloud-SDK\\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\\..\\platform\\bundledpython\\python.exe" "-S" "C:\\Users\\rajamannar_k\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Cloud-SDK\\google-cloud-sdk\\lib\\gcloud.py" compute start-iap-tunnel ssh-remote-vm %port --listen-on-stdin --project=project-name --zone=us-central1-a --verbosity=warning
    ProxyUseFdpass no
    User rajamannar_k
```

FYI: I'm using a windows machine.

Comment: refer to this documentation on [Connecting to Linux VMs using advanced methods](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#windows) you can also check this documentation since you are using [VS code using SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh)

Comment: @JonB regarding the GCP document for external ip they have provided 3 options using VPN, Bastion and IAP tunnel. Above two two option support terminal based development but I want to a GUI based integration which can be done using vs code. I looked into the vs code docs as well none has clear explanation on connecting one using proxycommand

Answer (score 0):

For those who are trying to connect to GCP-VM using SSH, which doesn't have an external IP, follow these steps for remote development using SSH in VS-Code.

For windows machines:

1. run the dry run command to generate the RSA key, this can be found inside `C:\Users\<your-username>\.ssh`. we will later use the response values in editing the config file, so keep it handy.

```
gcloud compute ssh vm-instance-name -zone vm-zone-location --tunnel-through-iap --dry-run
```

2. Post running the above command you will see a file google_compute_engine.pub inside the above directory. Open the file in an editor and copy the contents and paste it into the GCP VM's SSH section.
3. While pasting remove the struck word from your RSA and save it <strike>LENOVO-PC</strike>\your-username@Lenovo-PC. This will be found at the end of your key.
4. Create or edit the config file in the .ssh folder with the following, the values are from the `--dry-run` command.

```
Host compute.machine-no
  HostName compute.machine-no
  ForwardAgent yes
  IdentityFile C:/Users/<your-username>/.ssh/google_compute_engine
  ProxyCommand "python" "-S" "C:/Users/your-username/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py" compute start-iap-tunnel vm-instance-name 22 --listen-on-stdin --project=project-name --zone=vm-zone-location --verbosity=warning
  User your-username
```